# Как определить пересечения географический координат

Tags: карты, arduino

У меня есть GPS трекер на базе Arduino, которое будет помещено на движущий объект, он же будет получать текущие координаты движущего объекта.

Я пытаюсь найти расстояние между множествами точками (для которых у меня есть широты и долготы) я их изобразил в виде серой черты. На практике, их будет 3 или больше.

Мне нужно узнать на сколько объект приблизился к черте или сообщить когда он её пересек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если граница задана двумя точками, и представляет собой отрезок на поверхности (точнее, дугу большого круга), то можно использовать формулы с [данной страницы](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Раздел `bearing`

```
Formula:    θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where   φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the difference in longitude)
```

Нужно предварительно рассчитать величины азимута от первой точки границы ко второй `θ12` и от первой точки к персонажу `θ14`.

При движении объекта - считать направление от первой точки к объекту `θ13`, и сравнивать знак разности `θ13-θ12` c `θ14-θ12`

Если существенно, что проекция объект должна попадать на отрезок, а не на его продолжение - тогда смотреть разницы азимутов `θ13-θ12, θ21-θ23` (обе должны быть в пределах Pi/2)